# Find object by property key deep Javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have the following code:

You can go to jsbin here..
https://jsbin.com/wupukuhita/1/edit?js,console

```
var foundObjects = [];
var findObjectByLabel = function(obj, key) {

    var foundObject = [];    
    for(var i in obj) {
      if(typeof obj[i] === "object"){
        if(typeof obj[i][key] !== "undefined"){
            foundObjects.push(obj[i]);
        }
        findObjectByLabel(obj[i],key);
      }
    }
    return null;
};
```

I am iterating recursively over an object to find out if a certain property exists.
Then if it does exist, return the parent object.

You can check the jsbin link for a full example.

I do not like the foundObjects which is outside the function.

How can i put it inside the function and just return from the function the  objects that contain a certain property.

https://jsbin.com/wupukuhita/1/edit?js,console

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript closures which is basically a function inside another function and the second function can access the main function objects
see the full code here , it works the same as your except we return the array

```js
var foundObjects = function (obj,key) {
    var foundObject = [];
    var findObjectByLabel = function(obj,key) {
        for (var i in obj) {
            if (typeof obj[i] === 'object') {
                if (typeof obj[i][key] !== 'undefined') {
                    foundObject.push(obj[i]);
                }
                findObjectByLabel(obj[i], key);
            }
        }
        return null;
    };
    findObjectByLabel(obj,key);
    return foundObject ;
}


var mainObj = {
    name: 'MainForm', // main form
    type: 'Form',
    dirty: false,
    valid: true,
    Errors: [],
    formOrInputElements: [
        {
            name: 'Age', // normal input
            type: 'Text',
            value: '',
            dirty: true,
            valid1: true,
            test: {
                name: 'test',
                valid1: false,
            },
            Errors: [],
        },
        {
            name: 'CNP', // normal input
            type: 'Text',
            value: '',
            dirty: true,
            valid: true,
            Errors: [],
        },
    ],
};

let foundObject = foundObjects(mainObj, 'valid1');

console.log(foundObject[0]);
console.log(foundObject[1]);
```

Comment: a simple tutorial about closure here 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use `array#reduce` and iterate through each of the key values in object. In case of an array, recursively invoke the function 
for each object. In case of an object, invoke the function with that object.

```js
var mainObj = { name: "MainForm", type: "Form", dirty: false, valid: true, Errors: [], formOrInputElements: [ { name: "Age", type: "Text", value: "", dirty: true, valid1: true, test: { name: "test", valid1: false }, Errors: [] }, { name: "CNP", type:"Text", value: "", dirty: true, valid: true, Errors: [] } ] }

var findObjectByLabel = function(obj, key) {

  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((r, k) => {
    if (k === key) {
      r.push(Object.assign({}, obj));
    } else if (Array.isArray(obj[k])) {
      obj[k].forEach(x => r = r.concat(findObjectByLabel(x, key)));
    } else if (typeof obj[k] === 'object') {
      r = r.concat(findObjectByLabel(obj[k], key));
    }
    return r;
  }, []);

};

console.log(findObjectByLabel(mainObj, "valid1"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function findObjectByLabel(haystack, needle, buffer = []) {
    if (typeof haystack === 'object') {
        for (const prop in haystack) {
            const result = prop === needle ? [haystack] : findObjectByLabel(haystack[prop], needle);
            if (result.length > 0) {
                buffer = buffer.concat(result);
            }
        }
    }
    return buffer;
}


// Unit test
function test_findObjectByLabel() {
    const obj = {
        foo: {
            foo1: {
                item1: 'item1',
                item2: 'item2',
                item3: 'item3',
            },
            foo2: {
                item1: 'item1',
                item2: 'item2',
                item3: 'item3',
                subFoo: {
                    item1: 'item1',
                    item2: 'item2',
                    needle: 'needle',
                }
            }
        },
        bar: {
            bar1: {
                item1: 'item1',
                item2: 'item2',
                item3: 'item3',
            },
            bar2: {
                item1: 'item1',
                item2: 'item2',
                item3: 'item3',
                needle: 'needle',
            }
        },
    }

    const expected = [
        obj.foo.foo2.subFoo, // <-- contain "needle"
        obj.bar.bar2,        // <-- contain "needle"
    ];
    const actual = findObjectByLabel(obj, 'needle');

    if (JSON.stringify(actual) === JSON.stringify(expected)) {
        console.log('Pass');
        console.log('expected => ', JSON.stringify(expected, null, 4));
        console.log('actual   => ', JSON.stringify(actual, null, 4));
    } else {
        console.log('Fail');

        console.log('Actual')
        console.log(JSON.stringify(actual));
        console.log('is not equal to expected');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(expected));
    }
}

test_findObjectByLabel();
```